# Change the .net framework with visual studios 2013 and the xamarin plug in

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, xamarin

I am trying to change the .net framework for a android c# app in visual studios 2013. I tried to create a new project with .net framework 4.0 but I still get an error saying that my application is targeting the 4.5 framework. Does anyone know how to force this? The reason I am doing this is that I have a nuget package that uses the 4.0 framework, however if there is a way to get that nuget package to use the 4.5 framework that is an equally valid solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change the .net framework for an Android app. It will always be targeting MonoAndroid.

You cannot use a NuGet package that only assemblies for the .NET framework since they may use parts of the Xamarin Android API that is not supported.

So you are left with finding another NuGet package that supports Android projects or re-compiling the source code in an Android library project so it targets MonoAndroid, which may or may not work depending on what the source code does.

Comment: So follow up question. How would I download a nuget package and change the settings myself?

Comment: You cannot download the nuget package and change its target framework you would need to recompile it from source